# How do I use an existing PDF as a container?

Tags: pdf, steganography, commodore

I have a PDF (created from Word) for a game I wrote for an old 8-bit computer, and I'd like to embed the code for that game (binary, less than 32k) into that PDF.  This way, my emulator can load the program by reading the PDF, and the two can be stored and shared in one file.

You could call this a form of steganography.

I know a PDF has a tree structure and uses ASCII to define its components; is there a way to add inert, "orphan" elements that won't cause problems for PDF readers?  I think that would be the easiest way to do it.  But I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Find the PDF specification online; read it.

Comment: A publicly available copy is [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). It essentially is a copy of ISO 32000-1. Last year ISO 32000-2 was published but the former is still what generally is supported.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use a document attachment or a file attachment annotation.
 
Most PDF tools that are available support these features as they are pretty basic.